# jQueryUI tooltip with html content in title attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

Hi I have this problem [Jquery UI tooltip does not support html content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734105/jquery-ui-tooltip-does-not-support-html-content), I've tried every solutions but no one works out to me.
In fact I tried with this code and didn't work either

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('li.thumbnail a').tooltip({
            content: function () {
                return 'hola';
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

What could I do?

Comment: Are you sure your jQuery selector is finding any elements?

Answer (score 0):

No problem to put html in tooltips. Just be careful with html's special characters (replace them with html entities or alternate double " and single ' quotes) And if you want to make it dynamic, use .attr() instead of jQuery UI methods. I.e:

use:

```
$('selector').attr('title', 'content here' );
```

instead of:

```
$('selector').tooltip({content: 'content here'});
```

You'll find working examples in [this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/BhM3C/1/)