# Is there any free JS tooltip, which can load content from external html div content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

Hy.

There is html documentation what contains div with id, and I had to get tooltip to all page, what have tooltip, and tooltip show content what is in the html div. Look like this: [Javascript Tooltip](http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/javascript-tooltip#view1)  but this is not free. Any idea?

Comment: Questions asking to recommend a specific tool are considered off-topic for Stack Overflow. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for details.

Comment: use this qTip. http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/

Comment: Try to spend more time for searching! Duplication is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734105/jquery-ui-tooltip-does-not-support-html-content

Comment: You could use JQueryUI: https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style I hope it may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [jQuery QTip2 plugin](http://qtip2.com/).

It does load the external content

See this [`JSFIDDLE Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/craga89/L6yq3/) for implementation